# Excel VBA: Run-time error: A query with the name 'Table 0' already exists

Tags: excel, vba

What's wrong with this Excel recorded macro? It returns this error when I try re-running it:

```
Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
A query with the name 'Table 0' already exists.
```

It successfully loads an HTML table from https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/ when I record it.

### Code highlighted in yellow by the debugging VBA editor

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Header"", type text}, {""Date"", type date}, {""Weekday"", type text}, {""Holiday Name"", type text}, {""Holiday Type"", type text}, {""Where It is Observed"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

### Full VBA script

```
    Sub readTable()
    ' readTable Macro

        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Header"", type text}, {""Date"", type date}, {""Weekday"", type text}, {""Holiday Name"", type text}, {""Holiday Type"", type text}, {""Where It is Observed"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0"";Extended Properties=""""" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0]")
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End Sub
```

### Macro Steps

1. Selected the **Data** ribbon
2. Clicked **Get Data** > **From Other Sources** > **From Web**
3. Left **Basic** selected
4. In the **URL** field: entered https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/
5. Clicked **Table 0** and **Load**
6. The table successfully loads in Sheet2.

Comment: It's telling you you can't add a new query with the same name as an existing one.  Either delete the existing one, or change the name.

Comment: `Table 0` already exists from the first time you ran it - either give it a different name each time or delete it before adding it again.  Haven't looked into what code does that yet though. :)

Comment: Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827417/delete-a-query-from-excel-workbook-with-vba  on how to delete "Table 0" query before you issue the Add.  Suppress any errors if not found.

Comment: @donPablo - Alternatively, OP can check for the number of tables and just do say `Dim numTables as String // numTables = 2 // ...Queries.Add Name:= "Table " & numTables ...`.  (Note that the `2` would actually be retrieved programmatically, not a magic number)