# Get a static copy of worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that contains the query results - table. How do I get a new copy of this sheet each time when the query is updated? It is updated by running a macro - "update".

For example, if query has "A" data, it gets a copy of it with "A" data. Once query is updated and got "B" data, it should get a copy of it with "B" data, but the first copy of the sheet should remain unchanged with "A" data. And so on...
I update the query with a button which runs a macro.

I am using vba's copy method and calling it from "update" macro, but it is also updating all previous copies with new data.

```
Sub GetCopy()
    CurrentSheet.Copy After:=CurrentSheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you copy the sheet *including the query linked data*.

So after that you must destroy the link to the query:

Duplicate the worksheet, right-click in the copied table and select "unlink from data source". After that your data is pure data and not linked with a query anymore.

[image]

If you need to do that with VBA, record a macro to see how the code would look like or have a look at the [ListObject.Unlink method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.unlink).

Comment: When duplicating this way, It is duplicating the linked query too. Is there any way to avoid it? 
After unlinking the table from the data source, I am ending up with several copies of the query that needs to be deleted manually.

Comment: Yes you will need to delete the query after unlinking. Maybe [Delete a query from excel workbook with Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827417/delete-a-query-from-excel-workbook-with-vba) helps.