# Delete unwanted queries in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I delete all unwanted queries from the workbook?

```
Sub DeleteQuery()
    Dim queries As Variant
    queries = Array("q1", "q2", "q3")
    For Each qr In ThisWorkbook.queries
        'Not sure about the syntax of the following line
        If qr not in queries Then
        qr.Delete
    Next qr
End Sub
```

If the query is not in the list, then it should be deleted

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Query1").Delete
```

will not work, because the name of the unwanted queries are unclear

Comment: Hi, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827417/delete-a-query-from-excel-workbook-with-vba

Comment: Hi, thanks. But it still assumes that the unwanted query name is known

Comment: So what is the problem really? The fact `If qr not in queries Then` wouldnt work I assume, because `qr.Delete` is fine syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Application.Match` with the query name.

```
If IsError(Application.Match(qr.Name, queries, 0)) Then ' query name is not in list
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through your queries and then loop through your entire array to find a match, if no match exists then delete.

```vb
Sub testingPQ()

    Dim vQuery As Variant
    Dim arrQueries() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    arrQueries = Array("q1", "q2", "q3")


    For Each vQuery In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        'loop through array to check for each query
        For i = LBound(arrQueries) To UBound(arrQueries)
            If vQuery.Name = arrQueries(i) Then
                'do not delete
                Exit For
            End If
            If i = UBound(arrQueries) Then
                'delete - no match
                vQuery.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    Next vQuery

End Sub
```

Comment: @JvdV right, have updated, didn't read the OP post properly. This will do the trick.

Comment: @BigBen working in memory should be fine. Against it when not working in memory. :)

Comment: `If i = UBound(arrQueries)` - not sure this will work actually. What if the match happens on `i`?

Comment: ^ agreed. Maybe if you would put the array in a dictionary/arraylist and check if name `.Exists` then it's a nice way to avoid `IsError` and a second loop. However, `IsError` in the way @BigBen used, is legitimate too.

Comment: @BigBen it does, `UBound` returns `Long` type.

Comment: @BigBen it will `Exit For` before it reaches there.

Comment: @JvdV I agree with the dictionary!

Comment: Uggh sorry ignore - the Double `For` loop is throwing me off. Which is why... I second the dictionary idea.

Comment: @BigBen haha you were confusing me there for a minute!