# How to turn a query name into variable

Tags: sql, vba

i need to make repitative queries, but I've really stuck on queries names and have to change'em manually every time, like Name_1, Name_2 etc. The orignal code looks like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Name_1", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""C:\EXCHANGER\LastStage BOX"")
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
Sheets(2).Name = "INDEX"
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Name_1"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Name_1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Name_1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Tome make it dynamic, I have come with smth like this so far

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=i, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""C:\EXCHANGER\LastStage BOX"")

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
Sheets(2).Name = "INDEX"
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=i;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [i]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = i
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End
```

and the code rolls fine until it hits

```
.ListObject.DisplayName = i
```

which deals only with strings. Any workaround on this one, please?

Comment: `.ListObject.DisplayName = "lo_" & i` ?

Comment: It throws Run-time error '1004', and says that it can't find "i" query

Comment: Do you need this `.ListObject` too?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, i do. I tried it with (.ListObject.DisplayName = "lo_" & i) and  (.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False) line commented out, it worked, but it didn't pick the names of the spreadsheets to be referenced

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i finally found an answer. It's better to delete the current query in the end of the sub, instead of trying to make it dynamic via variable

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Name_1").Delete
```

[Delete a query from excel workbook with Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827417/delete-a-query-from-excel-workbook-with-vba)

Thanx for your input, guys, anyway!