# Why does CurrentDb return the error: "object required"?

Tags: vba

I wanna write a small code in Excel VBA to check if a query already exists. There are already a bunch of custom functions out there but nothing seems to work. It all seems to come down to one thing:

"db = CurrentDb" returns an error and I have no Idea why.

Here is the Code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb 'This line returns the error (object required)

For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
  If qdf.Name = "QueryName1" Then
    msgbox ("query already exists")
     Exit For
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Edit: Guess it has to do with the fact that I am using ADO ? Loading the DAO library just returns a DLL error so I just stuck to using ADO..

Anyone got an idea how to do this in ADO?

Comment: I just ran your code in MS Access and it worked just as intended. `CurrentDb` is an Access application method. If you are trying to use it in Excel then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I'm trying to to use it in Excel. 
Your answer already helped, I didnt know CurrentDb is an Access-specific global variable which is not defined in Excel.. 

So how do I solve this? Like I said I can't open the DAO 3.6 Database for some reason. It just returns: "error loading a DLL".
I also can't use  

Set Db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Tim\Databases\blabla.mdb") 

because I wanna use the Code on multiple Laptops with different paths.
At the end all I wanna do is check if a query already exists..

Comment: Access is a database. Excel is not. `CurrentDb` makes no sense in excel. Where are your querydefs? your table definitions? There aren't any. It would be like trying to use the MS Word table of contents object in excel. It makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now. Going by this example, you should be able to check if an excel query exists using `ActiveWorkbook.Queries` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767220/a-query-with-the-name-already-exists

Answer (score 1):

Okay first of all, thanks for the quick help. This Link helped me out quite a bit:
[a query with the name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767220/a-query-with-the-name-already-exists)

So to give a bit more context, I am building a macro in excel that loops through a dynamic list of URLs (APIs) and constructs a query for each of them. The name of the queries is based on their content.
The problem was: If the query (name) already exists the construction returns an error: A query with this name already exists.

What I wanted to do is to first check if the query exists, and if it does: skip the construction.

The solution to that was a lot easier than I thought. I just had to write the following code:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

directly before the "ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QryName, Formula:= _...." -Part. So if the AddQuery part returns an error, it just gets skipped.

Guess I got too hung up on trying to code a function to check if a query exists... my bad ^^

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.